# How does Jersey / Jax-RS picks the right method in a resource

Tags: java, rest, annotations, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I am using latest version of Jersey for an API server.
I defined the next resource:

```
@javax.ws.rs.Path("/myPath")
public class MyResource {

  @GET
  @Consumes({MediaType.WILDCARD, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, MediaType.TEXT_HTML})
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public Response method1(@Context Request request) {
  }

  @GET
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public MyObject method2() {}

}
```

Now lets say I am calling this resource with the next header:

```
<header>
    <name>Accept</name>
    <value>text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*</value>
</header>
```

How does Jersey knows which one to match to in this case where no method `Producer` annotation is matching?
I am asking because one time the server responded to the method2 and after restarting it, it responded to method1.

Comment: I Updated the ticket
I tested it.
I am not getting 406. I just restarted my server and the decision by Jersey is different.
I know about */* - but how does Jersey picks the right method to do it?

Comment: Looks closed, but they are talking only about "Path" level decision, and not about attributes decisions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<header>
    <name>Accept</name>
    <value>text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*</value>
</header>
```

I don't know what that it; headers aren't sent in XML, but assuming you sent the header correctly, here's how it's broken down.

`@Produces` handles the `Accept` header, and `@Consumes` handles the client `Content-Type` header, when the client sends data. So let's look at your two `@Produces` annotations, against the `Accept` header

```
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response method1() {}

@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public MyObject method2() {}

text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
```

So neither of them have `text/html`, so cross that out. Neither of them have `application/xhtml+xml`, so cross that out. That only leaves `*/*`, which means "send me whatever". **So Jersey is free to choose which one. The results are unpredictable. You can't make any assumptions about it.** And that's the client's fault. Not ours. The client should send the correct header. Or maybe we should do a better job documenting our API, so the client knows what types we can produce :-)

Comment: The header is just from a snapshot of the header using chrome developer tools.
I was expecting to get error if there is no matching.
So you are saying it is randomly picked if there is not clear match?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, where I have to methods with a specific `@Produces()` annotations. This trick works:

```java
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response method1() {}

@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, "*/*;q=0"})
public Response method2() {}
```

When using MIME types, you can add the `q` property, which indicates priority (0 to 1). The absence of the `q` property implies 1, but apparently the `q=0` tricks Jersey to use the other function.

It's kind of a hack, so I don't know if it will remain working, but helped me out.

Comment: This seems not to work anymore.